# Python - Scipy linear regression with nan values

Tags: python, scipy, linear-regression

I would like to obtain the slopes of the linear regression of my data, but the Y contains some nan values...thus it perturbs linregress function...
For example :

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

X = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
Y = np.array([np.NaN,4, 5, 10, 2, 5])
stats.linregress(X,Y)
```

But, I obtain :  (nan, nan, nan, nan, nan)
Thus i try to mask invalid values as you can see:

```
import numpy.ma as ma
stats.linregress((X),ma.masked_invalid(Y))
```

But it s the same...I dont see what i have to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Y=Y[np.logical_not(np.isnan(Y))]
X=X[np.logical_not(np.isnan(Y))]
```

upd: as Warren noticed, `Y` will be updated, so the `nans` are gone. You can feed `Y[np.logical_not(np.isnan(Y))]` and `X=X[np.logical_not(np.isnan(Y))]`
 directly into linear regression. Or see Warren's answer with `np.isfinite`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i think i have infinite number that provokes nan too... there is a same function for this case?

Comment: There is a problem with that solution.  The first line *changes Y*, so it no longer has any `nan`s.  Then, in the second line, `np.logical_not(np.isnan(Y))` will always be all True values, and if there were any `nan` in `Y` originally, the length of the boolean array will be less than the length of `X`, so it will simply discard values from the end of `X`.  Test it with the example given in the question, and you'll see that it does not do what you want.

Comment: True, but you get the idea, you can feed `Y[np.logical_not(np.isnan(Y))]` and `X[np.logical_not(np.isnan(Y))]` into linear regression.

Answer (score 4):

To remove (x, y) pairs where y is `nan` or `inf`, you can do this:

```
finiteYmask = np.isfinite(Y)
Yclean = Y[finiteYmask]
Xclean = X[finiteYmask]
```

If you are only using these "cleaned" arrays for `linregress`, you can do just:

```
finiteYmask = np.isfinite(Y)
```

and then call `linregress(X[finiteYmask], Y[finiteYmask])`

Comment: One suggestion: If you change the mask to `np.isfinite([X, Y]).all(axis=0)` it can handle nan values in X array too.

Comment: @ayhan This also helps to mask instances were `x` is `NaN` or `inf`but not `y`; right?

Comment: @Dataman Yes, by using `.all()` you are forcing both x and y to be finite.